# How does matalb function pc2surfacemesh find a suitable spherical radius for ball-pivoting algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, matlab, 3d-reconstruction

I was recently learning about the algorithm for reconstructing point cloud into meshe, and I focused on an algorithm called ball-pivoting. Looking through some open source code libraries, such as open3d, I found that the key to this algorithm is to find the right radius of the sphere. pc2surfacemesh in matlab is the first function I found to provide the optimal radius calculation, but the official website does not introduce the principle of the algorithm.
This is the official link to pc2surfacemesh : https://ww2.mathworks.cn/help/lidar/ref/pc2surfacemesh.html

Comment: Actually the linked website explains it quite detailed. You need to scroll down to the Algorithms section. There you'll find the steps for the ball-pivot reconstruction.

Comment: @Till The linked site does not seem to indicate how the radius is calculated

Comment: You're right, the calculation of the radii isn't explained, maybe it's the radius of the inner circle of the triangles. Unfortunately, I don't have a Matlab version that implements this function. But I'd suggest you to use the function on a very small and geometrically simple point cloud and try to understand how it works.